# Select explicitly columns using QueryOver from 2 tables

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Below is HQL query that I use to obtains all columns from **OrderDetail** table and Name column from **Item** table.

Could I do this using QueryOver in which I do not need to manually list all OrderDetail's columns in the Select clause of QueryOverProjectionBuilder statement, instead? Is there anyway to use "Select *" in QueryOver?

```
 IList<OrderDetail> lstOD =  Session.GetISession().CreateQuery("Select d, i.Name from OrderDetail d inner join d.Item i Where d.Order.Id = 1");
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: If you are trying to create a projection, then there is no way you can do that. If you are fine with returning a list of entities, then just don't specify a Select list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to do a `SELECT *` using `QueryOver`, unfortunately. This has been discussed on the NH Google Group a few times. If you really want something like this, then you can extend `QueryOver` to iterate over all of the properties you've mapped and build up a projection list under the covers.